# Cannot find numbers of pages of website in web scraping

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I want to take number of pages from web site. I try to do it like on [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-web-scraping-rvest). I used this function:

```
get_last_page <- function(html){

  pages_data <- html %>% 
                  # The '.' indicates the class
                  html_nodes('.pagination-page') %>% 
                  # Extract the raw text as a list
                  html_text()                   

  # The second to last of the buttons is the one
  pages_data[(length(pages_data)-1)] %>%            
    # Take the raw string
    unname() %>%                                     
    # Convert to number
    as.numeric()                                     
}
first_page <- read_html(url)
(latest_page_number <- get_last_page(first_page))
```

for website

```
url <-'http://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.amazon.com'
```

it works fine.When I tried to do it with

```
url <-'https://energybase.ru/en/oil-gas-field/index'
```

I got integer(0).

I change

```
html_nodes('.pagination-page')
```

to

```
html_nodes('.html_nodes('data-page')')
```

And failed.
How can I change my code to make it works fine?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to go about this a little differently here.

The energybase.ru [URL](https://energybase.ru/en/oil-gas-field/index) isn't organized quite the same way as the TrustPilot [URL](http://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.amazon.com).

For our purposes here, we're interested in the fact that the last page has its own node `.last`. From there, you just have to extract the value of the `data-page` attribute and increment it by 1.

```
library("rvest") 
library("magrittr")

url <- 'https://energybase.ru/en/oil-gas-field/index'

read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(".last") %>% html_children() %>% html_attr("data-page") %>% as.numeric()+1
# [1] 21
```

Edit: note, you can always intercept the piping at `html_children()` (by adding a `%>% html_attrs()` to it) to find out what attributes are available at your disposal there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the rel=last attribute=value node and extract the number from the href

```
library("rvest") 
library("magrittr")

pg <- read_html('https://energybase.ru/en/oil-gas-field/index')
number_of_pages <- str_match_all(pg %>% html_node("[rel=last]") %>% html_attr("href"),'page=(\\d+)')[[1]][,2] %>% as.numeric()
```

Or, there are a number of ways you could calculate it given that there are more pages than pagination visibile. One way is to get the total count from the appropriate li in the drop down and divide by the results per page count.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

pg <- read_html('https://energybase.ru/en/oil-gas-field/index')
total_sites <- strtoi(pg %>% html_node('#navbar-facilities > li:nth-child(13)') %>% html_attr('data-amount'), base = 0L)
# or use: total_sites <- pg %>% html_node('#navbar-facilities > li:nth-child(13)') %>% html_attr('data-amount') %>% as.numeric()
sites_per_page <- length(pg %>% html_nodes('.index-list-item'))
number_of_pages <- ceiling(total_sites/sites_per_page)
```